# Proving that $f(x) = 6\ln(x^{11}-4) -2$ is one-to-one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-writing, logarithms, solution-verification

*Please verify my proof, and if there are any mistakes please explain.*

**Prove that that this function is one-to-one: $f(x) = 6\ln(x^{11}-4) -2$.**

Suppose $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$
$\implies 6\ln(x_1^{11}-4) -2  = 6\ln(x_2^{11}-4) -2$

Then we have, $\ln(x_1^{11}-4) - \ln(x_2^{11}-4) = 0$

Using quotient rule for logarithms, $ \ln \frac{x_1^{11}-4}{x_2^{11}-4} = 0\implies e^0 = \frac{x_1^{11}-4}{x_2^{11}-4}$

Thus, $x_1^{11}-4 = x_2^{11}-4 \implies x_1 = x_2$.

So the function  $f(x) = 6ln(x^{11}-4) -2$ is one-to-one

Comment: Seems good to me

Comment: You could also argue that $f(x)$ is injective as a composition of injective functions ($6x-2, \ln(x),x^{11}-4$).

Comment: Might want to add $e^0 =1$ and $1 = \frac MN \implies M =N$ and that is why $e^0 =\frac MN$ implies $M=N$.... I mean, yeah, it's obvious and the reader must be a big dope if he can't fill in the details for himself but.... well, being thorough (but not excessively so) is its own reward.....

Comment: .... oh, and I guess maybe adding that $11$ is an odd power so it is one to one... then again one can be *too* thorough sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes your way is fine, as an alternative we can consider

$$g(x)=\frac{f(x)+2}6 = \ln(x^{11}-4), \quad h(x)=e^{g(x)}=x^{11}-4$$

and since $h(x)$ is one to one then also $g(x)$ is one to one and then also $f(x)$ is one to one.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\log a=\log b\implies a=b $. This reduces two steps.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, but it is simpler to do\begin{align}6\log(x_1^{\,11}-4)-2=6\log(x_2^{\,11}-4)-2&\iff\log(x_1^{\,11}-4)=\log(x_2^{\,11}-4)\\&\iff\exp\bigl(\log(x_1^{\,11}-4)\bigr)=\exp\bigl(\log(x_2^{\,11}-4)\bigr)\\&\iff x_1^{\,11}-4=x_2^{\,11}-4\\&\iff x_1=x_2.\end{align}

Comment: sorry, what does $exp$ mean?

Comment: @HaykKhachatryan Exponential function ($x\mapsto e^x$).